# Firebase security rules - difference in behaviour between Simulator and code

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

Data

```
"directChat" : {
  "creator" : {
    "1-L6HQZZSvJ0aarUmXdtN" : {
      "ID" : "XXX",
      "fbID" : "YYY",
      "name" : "Hari"
    }
  },
  "target" : {
    "1-L6HQZZSvJ0aarUmXdtN" : {
      "ID" : "ZZZ",
      "fbID" : "AAA",
      "name" : "John Doe"
    }
  }
}
```

Security Rule

```
"directChat": {
  "creator": {
    "$cID": {
      ".write": "data.val() == null && auth != null && newData.parent().parent().parent().child('directChat/creator/' + $cID + '/ID').val() == auth.uid",
      ".read": "auth != null && data.child('revealed').val() == true && root.child('directChat/target/' + $cID + '/ID').val() == auth.uid"
    },
    ".read": "auth != null && auth.uid == query.equalTo && query.orderByChild == 'ID'"
  }
}
```

Firebase Simulator

```
Simulation type - Read
Ref - /directChat/creator/1-L6HQZZSvJ0aarUmXdtN/
UID - XXX
```

Code

```
async runTests(){
  var creatorIsMe = await firebase.database().ref('directChat/creator/1-L6HQZZSvJ0aarUmXdtN/').once('value')
  console.warn('value1', creatorIsMe)
}
```

Simulation fails, which is the expected behaviour but my code returns the snapshot! What am I missing?

Comment: are you using an authenticated user?

Comment: Yes. I am. @PeterHaddad

Comment: then it is working correctly?

Comment: Something seems to be very wrong. Even the query restrictions aren't working. I am able to query directChat/creator created by another person.

Comment: No @PeterHaddad As per the rules it shouldn't allow me to access. And it doesn't via SImulator and stops at the right line. But it lets me access by code.

Comment: did you enable authentication in simulator?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165951/discussion-between-peter-haddad-and-hari).

Answer (score 1):

Found it after wasting around half day. Its due to offline persistence.

I started with a rule like auth!=null and it synced to offline cache. When I changed the rule to add more restrictions to data, the data does not sync and it keeps returning results from offline.

Thats bad firebase! Firebase offline persistence should treat Permission denied error differently from not being able to access the server data due to being offline/other reasons.

**Better not to have offline persistence enabled in dev mode.**